# Find content inside square brackets with PHP and replace (regex?)

Tags: php, regex, brackets

I need to convert this:

```
[video=http://example.com/video.flv]
```

Into this:

```
<a href="http://example.com/myVideo.flv" id="player"></a>
```

Using PHP - probably regex. A string can contain many of these 'code blocks' and I need to give each video a unique ID. How can I do this? I am sorry, I really don't know much about regex.

Comment: Other relevant BBCode parsing: [Specifically convert only YouTube urls to iframe tags while converting BBCode urls to html elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53087161/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if they are all standard in their format, why not just use str_replace()?

```
$s = '[video=http://www.site.com/video.flv]';
$url = str_replace(array('[video=',']'),array('',''),$s);
echo '<a href="'.$url.'">click me!</a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$cnt = 0;
preg_replace('/\[.*?=(.*?)]/e', '<a href="$1" id="video' . $cn++ . '">$1</a>', $text);
```

not tested, will probably blow up and steal your dog, etc...

Comment: It does break, gives me this error:
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /data01/virt30189/domeenid/www.ipbpartners.eu/htdocs/extensions/ipb/smarty_plugins/outputfilter.content_strtoupper.php(34) : regexp code on line 1

Fatal error: preg_replace() [<a href='function.preg-replace'>function.preg-replace</a>]: Failed evaluating code: &lt;a href=&quot;http://vod01.netdna.com/vod/demo.flowplayer/Extremists.flv&quot; id=&quot;player-0&quot;&gt;http://vod01.netdna.com/vod/demo.flowplayer/Extremists.flv/a&gt; in ... on line 34`

Comment: How could you use the `e` modifier :O