# Specifically convert only YouTube urls to iframe tags while converting BBCode urls to html elements

Tags: php, regex, youtube, preg-replace, bbcode

I'm trying to convert youtube video links into iframes to embed them onto my website but I'm having a problem as I am already converting urls to anchor tags and it's conflicting with the youtube url.

Here is my code:

```
$string = 'https://www.google.com and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=umFQckeDwEE';
$url = '~(\s|^)(https?://.+?)(\s|$)~im';
$string = preg_replace($url, '[url=$0]$0[/url]', $string);
$youtubeURL = '/\s*[a-zA-Z\/\/:\.]*youtu(be.com\/watch\?v=|.be\/)([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)([a-zA-Z0-9\/\*\-\_\?\&\;\%\=\.]*)/i';
$string = preg_replace($youtubeURL, '<iframe width=\"420\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/$2\" allowfullscreen></iframe>', $string);
```

The first line gets anything that is just a plain url as I am using BBCode it conflicted with other stuff like the `[img]` tag. The `$youtubeURL` is to get all youtube links and turn them into iframes but because of the first link conversion it causes an `href` to be put in the `scr=`.

Comment: Volunteers, you may find it helpful to view this OP's previous question for more context about the question.

Comment: And this may be valuable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48968340/2943403

Comment: So basically for each one you want to not match url's that are contained within a BBCode tags ?

Comment: I want to be able to convert only youtube links to iframes, so ones that don't contain any BBCode or just a regular link like google.com

Comment: Use these `$url = '~(?>\[[^\[\]]*\](*SKIP)(*FAIL)\s*)*\s*\Khttps?://.+?(?!\S)~';`

`$youtubeURL = '~(?>\[[^\[\]]*\](*SKIP)(*FAIL)\s*)*\s*[a-zA-Z/:.]*youtu(be\.com/watch\?v=|\.be/)([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)([a-zA-Z0-9/*_?&;%=.-]*)~';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launching from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53072440/2943403), I've developed and tested a complete battery of regular expressions to get you on your way.  I will admit that this set of pattern could be refined further to be more condensed (fewere total patterns) and that the youtube validation patterns could be more strict, but I honestly don't have time to go down those rabbit holes.

When considering the compexity/diversity of youtube urls, you may want to reference this list of examples that I pulled from StackOverflow pages and the internet.  https://regex101.com/r/zinjze/1

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/tIVlj))

```
$bbcode = <<<BBCODE
Want a list?
[ul][li]Here is a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mUxt--mMjwA[/li]
[li]This is a [b]tagged[/b] video: [url]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u6MyOXk98DI[/url][/li]
[li]This is a [b]tagged & attributed[/b] video: [url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8G2WzH4AKpE]Pearl Jam - Present Tense[/url][/li]
[li]Look at this:https://www.example.com/example?ohyeah=sure#okay this is a raw link[/li]
[li][i]No attribute[/i] bbcode url: [url]http://example.com/x1[/url][/li]
[li]A url with link and link text: [url=http://example.com/x2]x2[/url][/li]
[li]Image with \"ignorable" text: [IMG=https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/be/Portrait_of_Julie_Bishop.jpg/220px-Portrait_of_Julie_Bishop.jpg]Julie Bishop[/IMG][/li]
[li]Image: [img=https://docs.joomla.org/images/3/37/Joomla-3D-Vertical-logo-light-background-en.png][/img][/li]
[li][quote]"I could either watch it happen or be a part of it."[/quote]
    - Elon Musk[/li]
[li][user=2943403]mickmackusa[/user][/li]
[li]Code: 
[code]while (\$noSuccess) {
    tryAgain();
    if (\$dead) break;
}[/code][/li]
[/ul]
BBCODE;

$search = array (
    '~\[b](.*?)\[/b]~is',
    '~\[i](.*?)\[/i]~is',
    '~\[u](.*?)\[/u]~is',
    '~\[ul](.*?)\[/ul]~is',
    '~\[li](.*?)\[/li]~is',
    '~\[user=(.*?)](.*?)\[/user]~i',
    '~\[url=https?.*?(?:[/?&](?:e|vi?|ci)(?:[/=]|%3D)|youtu\.be/|embed/|/user/[^/]+#p/(?:[^/]+/)+)([\w-]{10,12})].*?\[/url]~i',
    '~\[url]https?.*?(?:[/?&](?:e|vi?|ci)(?:[/=]|%3D)|youtu\.be/|embed/|/user/[^/]+#p/(?:[^/]+/)+)([\w-]{10,12}).*?\[/url]~i',
    '~\[url=((?:ht|f)tps?://[a-z\d.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}/\S*?)](.*?)\[/url]~i',
    '~\[url]((?:ht|f)tps?://[a-z\d.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}/\S*?)\[/url]~i',
    '~\[img=(.*?)].*?\[/img]~i',
    '~\[quote](.*?)\[/quote]~is',
    '~\[code](.*?)\[/code]~is',
    '~(?:<a.*?</a>|<img.*?</img>|<iframe.*?</iframe>)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?:\bhttps?.*?(?:[/?&](?:e|vi?|ci)(?:[/=]|%3D)|youtu\.be/|embed/|/user/[^/]+#p/(?:[^/]+/)+)([\w-]{10,12}))\S*~i',
    '~(?:<a.*?</a>|<img.*?</img>|<iframe.*?</iframe>)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\bhttps?://.+?(?=\s|$)~im'
);

$replace = array (
    '<strong>$1</strong>',
    '<em>$1</em>',
    '<u>$1</u>',
    '<ul>$1</ul>',
    '<li>$1</li>',
    '<a href="../login/profile?u=$1" target="_blank">$2</a>',
    '<iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
    '<iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
    '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$2</a>',
    '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>',
    '<img src="$1"></img>',
    '<quote>$1</quote>',
    '<code>$1</code>',
    '<iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
    '<a href="$0" target="_blank">$0</a>'
);    

echo preg_replace($search, $replace, $bbcode);
```

Unrendered Output: (**you can copy-paste my snippet in http://phptester.net/ if you want to see the rendered output**)

```
Want a list?
<ul><li>Here is a video: <iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mUxt--mMjwA" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<li>This is a <strong>tagged</strong> video: <iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/u6MyOXk98DI" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
<li>This is a <strong>tagged & attributed</strong> video: <iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8G2WzH4AKpE" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
<li>Look at this:<a href="https://www.example.com/example?ohyeah=sure#okay" target="_blank">https://www.example.com/example?ohyeah=sure#okay</a> this is a raw link</li>
<li><em>No attibute</em> bbcode url: <a href="http://example.com/x1" target="_blank">http://example.com/x1</a></li>
<li>A url with link and link text: <a href="http://example.com/x2" target="_blank">x2</a></li>
<li>Image with \"ignorable" text: <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/be/Portrait_of_Julie_Bishop.jpg/220px-Portrait_of_Julie_Bishop.jpg"></img></li>
<li>Image: <img src="https://docs.joomla.org/images/3/37/Joomla-3D-Vertical-logo-light-background-en.png"></img></li>
<li><quote>"I could either watch it happen or be a part of it."</quote>
    - Elon Musk</li>
<li><a href="../login/profile?u=2943403" target="_blank">mickmackusa</a></li>
<li>Code: 
<code>while ($noSuccess) {
    tryAgain();
    if ($dead) break;
}</code></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Wow you are a saint! I've never seen someone on here help me this much, I usually only ask for questions here expecting a little bit of help but wow, you deserve some sort of medal dude. The only thing I can think of improving this is twitch.tv embedding. I've tried to copy your code for the youtube one but can't quite get it right.

Comment: Show me a regex101 demo of twitch urls and your pattern, I'll have a look.  (Yes, I am going rather above and beyond with your revent questions; you shouldn't expect this level of care on a regular basis.)

Comment: for twitch clips it looks like this https://clips.twitch.tv/embed?clip='CLIPNAMEHERE' that's literally I want, I don't want you to spend way more time than you already have, honestly you're a God on this site lol

Comment: Just realised my attempt was wrong as the original link should be clips.twitch.tv/‘CLIPNAMEHERE’`'~(?:<a.*?</a>|<img.*?</img>|<iframe.*?</iframe>)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?:\bhttps?.*?(?:[/?&](?:e|vi?|ci)(?:[/=]|%3D)|clips\.twitch\.tv/[^/]+#p/(?:[^/]+/)+)([\w-]))\S*~i',` after the conversion it goes to /embed?clip=

Comment: Well for clips the only way I know is clips.twitch.tv/clipname there are other variations for channels, collections etc but I pretty much only want the clips to convert to iframe. There’s more info here:  https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/embed/video-and-clips/ but I really can’t ask you to do all this for me you’ve done way more than I even expected.

Comment: I honestly can't thank you enough. I would love to learn all the different regex expressions myself. I am a student myself and don't get all the time to learn this. I learnt some php in a web class two years ago and a lot of my website I have built myself with the odd time I come here asking for help when I've tried a dozen times.

Comment: Good, then you are using StackOverflow properly.  I'm happy to help you out any time.  And if there is anything in particular about my regex patterns that you don't understand, (after researching) you are welcome to ask me.

Comment: Hey sorry to bother you again I've just noticed an error on that last regex, if I add a string after the video clip it adds that to the html and therefore the video doesn't display. I've been trying for hours to fix it.

Comment: Which pattern? please show me a demo of the error. I'll have a look when I get out of bed.

Comment: The comment you made 2 days ago `'~(?:<a.*?</a>|<img.*?</img>|<iframe.*?</iframe>)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\bhttps?://(?:www:)?clips\.twitch\.tv/\?video=([^&]+)\S*~i'` its getting the link and embedding it but anything else in the string afterwards gets added on. I tried for ages to fix it doing checks like if there’s a `/` at the end or not or using all sorts of different expressions.

Comment: With that it only gets the first character

Comment: I tried adding `.` after the `[^&]+?` which separated the strings but still only gets the first character.

Comment: I don't remember if twitch video ids are alphanumeric. Maybe use `\w+`.  If that doesn't work, send me a regex101 link with the pattern and ten different example twitch urls.

Comment: Worked perfectly! For twitch clips they only look like this `https://clips.twitch.tv/SparklyGrotesqueStingrayPMSTwin` just a long string at the end, all letters no numbers I'm pretty sure. By the way is there anyway I can give you credit or something for all this hard work you've done?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix my problem by swapping my code around so it converts YouTube links first then the other URLs second and changing it a little. New code:

```
$youtubeURL = '/\s*[a-zA-Z\/\/:\.]*youtube.com\/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)([a-zA-Z0-9\/\*\-\_\?\&\;\%\=\.]*)/i';
$string = preg_replace($youtubeURL, '<br><iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/$1$3" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe><br>', $string);
$url = '~(\s|^)(https?://.+?)(\s|$)~im';
$string = preg_replace($url, '<a href="$0">$0</a>', $string);
```